# Add breakpoint through code

Tags: java, debugging

If we add conditional breakpoints in java, the debugging becomes slow. is there a way we can add some statement which will cause the process of flow to stop there.
for eg.

```
    if(r>5 &&r<10)
    {
     stopExcecutionFlowAndStartDebugging();
     }
```

Comment: Why not just put a normal breakpoint on that line?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897594/debugbreak-equivalent-in-java

Comment: the code is flowing through that piece of code hundreds of time.Adding conditional breakoints is causing the eclipse to crash/or too slow to work with.

Comment: Not a conditional breakpoint - a normal one. See christopher's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Breakpoints are not Java. Breakpoints are IDE specific. Ergo, a Java method call isn't going to force the IDE to stop running normally and start debugging, because it isn't Java that initiates that in the first place.

But, and I'm sure you've already considered this, what's wrong with:

```
if(r > 5 && r < 10) {
    methodCall() // Add break point here.
}
```

Comment: I am pulling data from database having records in order of millions and processing it in batches. I know the set (the range of val) where the issue is occurrring. But am not sure where exactly in processing of the data the issue is occurring. Also the issue seems to be with data only but need to figure out what. So want a way when this batch starts to process, the debugging should start. Conditional breakpoints are causing eclipse to crash/and anyways making a slow process very very slow

Comment: I can add a break point there but the process is passing through that peice of code for hundreds of times

Comment: So then you need to work out your conditions a little bit better. Try to narrow down exactly *why* the error is happening, and you'll be able to tailor your `if statement` to meet that need.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a conditional breakpoint, but the solution will depend on your IDE. For Eclipse: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F

But if you asking if you can switch between debugging and not debugging, then the answer is no. All you can do is control where you put the breakpoints and how you use them.